# Javanet programing for work

Tags: java

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset.

Our application is written in Java and runs on top of Tomcat 5.5. It was written by contractors who are no longer with us. The current team has no real Java expertise, and we are unsure as to where the Connection reset error is actually coming from, and how to go about debugging.

The issue appears to be completely intermittent, and unrelated.
I'm already try some solutions, asked my friends, but i don't have any solution.

Comment: Flagged as should be closed because too broad. Please let your team learn about debuggin in their environment

Comment: wireshark the communication of your prgram and see exactly what is being sent and what you expect to get back when communicating

Answer (score 0):

Connection Reset, or ECONNRESET will be received if the peer:

1. Reboots, or
2. Disables linger before closing

Either way, the problem is with the peer your application is talking to, not your application, unless your application can make the peer crash.